# Reading values from a file which contains associative array PHP

Tags: php, arrays

I need to read the content of a file called *orders.log* with PHP and use the variables. The log file is stored like this:

```
Array
(
    [time] => 2099-99-99 00:00:00
    [gateway] => Paypal
    [gatewayOK] => Yes
    [gatewayTransactionId] => XXXXXXX
    [POST] => Array
        (
            [mc_gross] => 9.99
            [protection_eligibility] => Eligible
            [address_status] => confirmed
            [payer_id] => XXXXX
            [address_street] => XXXXX
            [payment_date] => 00:00:00 Nov 11, 2018 PDT
            [payment_status] => Completed
            [charset] => windows-1252

        )

)
```

I have tried reading it like this:

```
<?php
$orders=file_get_contents("orders.log");
echo $orders['time'];
echo $myarray[0]['gateway'];
echo $myarray[1]['mc_gross']; 
?>
```

But the result does not work like intended. It throws "A" and "r" . Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Is the content of the file literally as you show?  Can you change this and save it as something useful like JSON instead?

Comment: yes sadly I need to read the file as it is. I can not parse it to JSON or any other format.

Comment: Is every record in the same format - as in exactly the same fields on the same line?

Comment: yes it is. Just another array set that declares another order.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This assumes that each entry is 20 lines long, it reads in the log file and the splits it into 20 segments using `array_chunk()`.

It then processes each segment, first splitting the lines by the `=>` using `explode()` and adding the values to an associative array with the left hand side as the key.  You can then use the key to access each value.

```
$input = file("log.txt", FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES);

$orders = array_chunk($input, 20);
foreach ( $orders as $order )   {
    $split = [];
    foreach ( $order as $line ) {
        $info = explode("=>", $line);
        if ( count($info) == 2){
            $split[trim($info[0]," \t[]")] = trim ($info[1]);
        }
    }

    echo "gateway-".$split['gateway'].PHP_EOL;
    echo "mc_gross-".$split['mc_gross'].PHP_EOL;
}
```

If you wanted a list of all orders...

```
$input = file("log.txt", FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES);

$orders = array_chunk($input, 20);
$orderList = [];
foreach ( $orders as $order )   {
    $split = [];
    foreach ( $order as $line ) {
        $info = explode("=>", $line);
        if ( count($info) == 2){
            $split[trim($info[0]," \t[]")] = trim ($info[1]);
        }
    }
    $orderList[] = $split;
}


echo "gateway-".$orderList[0]['gateway'].PHP_EOL;
echo "mc_gross-".$orderList[0]['mc_gross'].PHP_EOL;
```

A third way which doesn't rely on the data being all the same format, this reads on a line by line basis and tries to work out the end of an element itself (just a line containing `)`)...

```
$fp = fopen("log.txt", "r");
$orderList = [];
$order = [];
while ( $line = fgets($fp)) {
    // Remove extra data after content
    $line = rtrim($line);
    // If end of order (a line just starting with a ')')
    if ( $line == ')' ) {
        // Convert order into associative array
        $split = [];
        foreach ( $order as $line ) {
            $info = explode("=>", $line);
            if ( count($info) == 2){
                $split[trim($info[0]," \t[]")] = trim ($info[1]);
            }
        }
        // Add data to order list
        $orderList[] = $split;
        $order = [];
    }
    else {
        // Add line to existing data
        $order[] = $line;
    }
}

print_r($orderList);
fclose($fp);
```

Comment: There is a way if you can't rely on the details always being 20 lines long - let me know if you have this problem.

Comment: Well the file also contains a couple of blank datasets like this Array
(
    [time] => 2018-11-10 08:11:41
    [gateway] => Stripe
    [gatewayOK] => Yes
    [gatewayTransactionId] => 
    [POST] => Array
        (
        )

    [GET] => Array
        (
        )

)

Comment: As you will end up with an array of segments, you could probably process them after to see which ones you need.  The last code example works on variable sized elements.

Comment: Yep I adjusted variables to my need and seems to work perfectly. Thank you.